# get user to upload a file and go in controller for file manipulation after one click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file

I'm trying to add an import CSV button to my rails application.

I want the user workflow to be like this:

1. click the "import CSV" button
2. select the desired CSV file and click confirm
3. see the csv file they just selected is now displayed in the application

but I don't know how to do it using only one click.

I searched the web and I see people do it by first getting the user to select a "select file" field and then click form submission button.

For example: `form_tag` plus `file_field_tag`

This is 2 clicks, I don't want this.

How do I just

1. have a button
2. user click on the button
3. user select the file using popup box and confirm the pop box
4. The code goes to controller without any other action from user
5. I do the things I want in controller

?

Comment: you can use `OnChange` event of Input file field and save `submission button` click.

Comment: as mentioned above you can use OnChange event and submit file via jquery then perform things you want in controller and render the partial to display results to user if you want.